# Removing a character from a string while leaving substrings of that character repeated sequentially intact

Tags: python, string

I have a string that I want to remove a certain character from. However, I do not want to remove instances of that character if it appears multiple times in a row. For example, I want to remove "a" from a string, but I do not want to remove any substrings such as "aa", "aaa", etc. I know how to do the opposite of this (replacing multiple characters in a row while leaving lone characters in the string) using regex, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to use `re.sub` + lambda function:

```py
import re

s = 'aXaaXaXaaXa'

s = re.sub(r'a+', lambda g: '' if len(g[0]) == 1 else g[0], s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
XaaXXaaX
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a negative lookahead `(?!...)` and a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)`:

```
import re

def remove_except_when_repeated(s: str, ch: str) -> str:
    pattern = "(?<!{0}){0}(?!{0})".format(ch)
    return re.sub(pattern, "", s)

print(f"{remove_except_when_repeated('abaacadaeafaa', 'a') = }")
```

**Output:**

```
remove_except_when_repeated('abaacadaeafaa', 'a') = 'baacdefaa'
```

Answer (score 1):

With a regular expression you can use negative lookahead and look behind:

```
s = "abaacaaadaeaa"

import re

re.sub(r'(?<!a)a(?!a)','',s)

'baacaaadeaa'
```

Without the re module you can use 4 replaces (assuming '|' or some other character of your choosing is never in the string):

```
s.replace("a","|a|").replace("||","").replace("|a|","").replace("|","")

'baacaaadeaa'
```

Another trick would be to use groupby from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "abaacaaadaeaa"

''.join(c*len(g) for c,(*g,) in groupby(s) if g != ['a'])

'baacaaadeaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to do the opposite of this (replacing multiple characters in a row

You could do that. Just replace them with themselves:

```py
import re

s = 'aXaaXaXaaXa'

s = re.sub(r'(aa+|[^a])|a', r'\1', s)
print(s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3fTJzC_KLShSKUrm4ihVsFdQTIxKBCEyoQ4SKUvWKS5M0itQ1EhO1a6LjEmM1axLVdRSK1GMMgVSxJldBUWZeiUaxJsRMqNEwKwA)